# Is there a way to add custom alt text to custom marker in google maps to improve SEO rating?

Tags: html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, seo

I'm facing a problem with google maps API as one of the customers of my company asked for the `alt` attribute on the marker image.

I cannot find anything in official Google documentation (i.e.: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/custom-markers) and cannot even find anything elsewhere about the `alt` text for google maps marker.
Personally, I don't even know if it has some effect on the SEO (as stated by a third-party company that the customer referred to, as they ran some SEO checks on their website).

I tried to use the examples from google and tried to add a hypothetical `alt` instruction, but, of course, it's not being picked up.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Simple Map</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
        /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
        #map {
            height: 100%;
        }
        /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
        html, body {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
        // Initialize and add the map
        function initMap() {
            // The location of Uluru
            var uluru = { lat: -25.344, lng: 131.036 };
            // The map, centered at Uluru
            var map = new google.maps.Map(
                document.getElementById('map'), { zoom: 4, center: uluru });
            // The marker, positioned at Uluru
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: uluru,
                map: map,
                title: 'Uluru',
                alt: 'my alternate text goes here'
            });
        }
    </script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=***********************&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
</body>
</html>
```

The after-rendering result is similar to the following:

```html
<img alt="" src="https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/api-3/images/spotlight-poi2.png" draggable="false" usemap="#gmimap0" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 27px; height: 43px; user-select: none; border: 0px; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; max-width: none; opacity: 1;">
```

Is there any way I can get something like:

```html
<img alt="my alternate text goes here" src="https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/api-3/images/spotlight-poi2.png" draggable="false" usemap="#gmimap0" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 27px; height: 43px; user-select: none; border: 0px; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; max-width: none; opacity: 1;">
```

---

UPDATE:

[image: partial rendered code screenshot]

Comment: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/69541792

Comment: As you can see from the above link, Maps have quite a few *accessibility* issues. That said I don't think that missing alt tags on markers images will have an (any) impact on the website global SEO. And there would be other ways to somehow "reference" these markers on the page, if that's the goal. Sounds like the other company just ran a SEO check and sent the results without much interpretation...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) I don't think it will have any impact on SEO: the markers are dynamically rendered and afaik Google only parses static HTML and some content rendered by JS but I haven't seen it run Maps API calls, I'd have noticed it in my API traffic). It would be probably much more helpful to generate a page summary in JSON-LD: https://json-ld.org/

2) If you MUST add an alt tag (I don't see why) or you want to display a hover tooltip next to the marker, you have to look at extending the `google.maps.OverlayView()` to create your own custom marker: this object has a `draw` prototype method that will allow you put anything on the map, any way you want it: an `<img alt=...>`,  a `<div>` etc.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/overlay-view
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/overlay-simple

3) Since you rely on Google correctly parsing JS output: why not try to add the alt tag post-factum (after map load) like (jQuery) `$('img[alt=""]').attr('alt','Now I fixed it')` ;)

Comment: Unless G changed its engine lately, it's been years since it reads rendered js (i.e.: https://searchengineland.com/tested-googlebot-crawls-javascript-heres-learned-220157 - also... it wouldn't be able to index SPAs, but it does...)
On the other hand, I can have a look at ```draw()```. I never used it. Thank you for the hint.

Comment: I think this is more to the point of what Google does: https://seopressor.com/blog/javascript-seo-how-does-google-crawl-javascript/ What I don't think it does is to run the Google Maps API calls. I would have seen it as API calls traffic in my sites... I do suggest you check JSON-LD, it's the proper way to define weird interactive content in a page, not compulsively trying to add an alt tag to any and every image you can find, but that's just my 2 cents...

Comment: Thanks for the link. It looks promising and interesting. I'll read it all the way down when I'll be home.
As I said in the original post, I don't think there is any value in that specific ```alt``` or if it has some sort of impact, but, before answering back to the client that a third company that they paid is supposedly saying something wrong/incorrect, I need to be a bit more sure (therefore the question here on SO).
I totally agree on the JSON-LD, but it would be too hard to implement it correctly on the current system, so I can't use that approach for now.

Comment: That's why I added the `seo` tag, maybe you'll get some more feedback on the matter.

Comment: See also the 3rd idea :)

Comment: The third idea is, probably, the fastest/simplest I can set in place and, to be fair, the one I like the most for this specific purpose. The `draw` looks the neatest approach though. Thank you.